# CORS and PATCH error in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cors, patch

I´m working on an angular app and have to send some CORS requests to the webservice. GET and POST work as expected, but I always get the "Method PATCH is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response." Error. 
Request and Response Headers are below. Any idea whats the problem here?

When I send the same request in Postman, everything works finde - I think it doesn´t do the preflight testing?

Request

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.6,es;q=0.4,fr;q=0.2,pt;q=0.2,nb;q=0.2
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:PATCH
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
DNT:1
Host:192.168.100.101:8081
Origin:http://zav.frontend.build
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://zav.frontend.build/provider/settings/account_data
```

Response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-    With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:*
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Allow:HEAD,GET,OPTIONS,PATCH
Content-Length:1697
Content-Type:application/vnd.sun.wadl+xml
Date:Fri, 26 Aug 2016 08:53:03 GMT
Last-modified:Fr, 26 Aug 2016 10:53:03 MESZ
```

Comment: How about Firefox? And maybe you can specify `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` with `PATCH` method.

Comment: good tip: Firefox gives me the same error, but hints, that PATCH was not found in the Acces-Control-Allow-Method, so maybe PATCH does not work with the wildcard. I´ll test it with explicitly allowing PATCH

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the wildcard `*` for `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` was only added to Chrome's source code in September 2017: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=615313 - looks like it made it into Chrome 63 (stable release December 2017).